# assign sorted dates without whitespace power bi

Tags: forms, datatable, powerbi, dax, lookup

I have the following tables, I want to add the date to the second table, I use a formula in DAX to do the lookup but I get the following

```
table1

prov    user     xs   
ala     user2    x     
ala     user3    xx   
ala     user4    xxx   
ala     user5    xxxx  

table2
prov    user     xs   date
ala     user2    x     01/02/2021
ala     user3    xx    17/07/2022
ala     user4    xxx   23/01/2023
ala     user5    xxxx  12/05/2023
```

table to get

```
prov  user1   date1       user2    date2        user3     date3       user4      date4
ala   user2   01/02/2021  user3   17/07/2022    user4     23/01/2023   user5   12/05/2023
```

I use the following formula

```
date1= IF('table2'[xs] = "x",'table2'[date], BLANK())
date2= IF('table2'[xs] = "xx",'table2'[date], BLANK())
date3= IF('table2'[xs] = "xxx",'table2'[date], BLANK())
date4= IF('table2'[xs] = "xxxx",'table2'[date], BLANK())
```

but i get the following

```
 prov  user1   date1       user2    date2       user3     date3       user4      date4
ala   user2   01/02/2021  user3                 user4                 user5   
ala   user2               user3   17/07/2022    user4                 user5  
ala   user2               user3                 user4   23/01/2023    user5 
ala   user2               user3                 user4                 user5      12/05/2023
```

Comment: You need to [SUMMARIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax) your data

Comment: I think your Table2 is enough to get your required output in  a Matrix visual.